# Workflow SP 2013 - Cannot retrieve a UserMulti Field value

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, workflow, sharepoint-addin

I'm developing a SharePoint-hosted App with a workflow working with a List that contains a UserMulti Field. I'm currently trying to retrieve this field value to a variable with a GetDynamicValueProperties but this isn't working, the workflow execution is hanging.

My workflow configuration is OK since I can retrieve the Title to a string variable for example but when I try to get the USerMulti Field (called 'Members') to a Object variable, nothing happen.

After [setting up my environment](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/SP2013-Workflow-Advanced-Workflow-Debugging-with-Fiddler) to catch the HTTP traffic I was able to find something in the XML conversation :

```
<WorkflowStatusDetails>RequestorId: d05baf50-adbc-6aa7-0000-000000000000. Details: RequestorId: d05baf50-adbc-6aa7-0000-000000000000. Details: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow instance. Exception details: System.InvalidOperationException: Looking up a value using a key is not supported on an instance of 'Microsoft.Activities.Dynamic.DynamicJsonPrimitive'.
  at Microsoft.Activities.Dynamic.DynamicItem.TryGetValue(String key, DynamicItem& value)
  at Microsoft.Activities.Dynamic.DynamicValueBuilder.PathSegmentFactory.ObjectPathSegment.Get(DynamicItem obj)
  at Microsoft.Activities.Dynamic.DynamicValueBuilder.PathSegmentFactory.ObjectPathSegment.Get(DynamicItem obj)
  at Microsoft.Activities.Dynamic.DynamicValueBuilder.PathSegmentFactory.ArrayPathSegment.Get(DynamicItem obj)
  at Microsoft.Activities.Dynamic.DynamicValueBuilder.PathSegmentFactory.ObjectPathSegment.Get(DynamicItem obj)
  at Microsoft.Activities.Dynamic.DynamicValueBuilder.PathSegmentFactory.ObjectPathSegment.Get(DynamicItem obj)
  at Microsoft.Activities.GetODataProperties.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
  at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
  at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)</WorkflowStatusDetails>
```

Can somebody enlighten me on that error or how to properly use a UserMulti Field in a Workflow ?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 3):

1. When you get value from user field, use it's name + "Id", in your case - MembersId.
2. Get your MultyUser field value to a `DynamicValue` variable (members).
   [image]
3. Use GetDynamicValueProperties tool with your DynamicValue variable (members) as a source to get it's results to a `Collection<String>` variable (membersIds).
   [image]
4. Then you can retrieve your `Collection<String>` variable with a simple indexation.
   [image]

Comment: Hi, how did you learn this information? I can't find ANY documentation at all!!

Comment: Hi, I've found it by research, by trial and error method :) There is really lack of documentation about SP Workflow 2013...